# PHP - cURL + strpos Issues

Tags: php, curl

I have a script in which checks if the tested netflix account works.
For some reason it just refuses to work I dont know what im doing wrong.

The Checker Page's PHP EDIT:
Added the if statement so it doesnt post blank just going to the page:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['e']) && isset($_POST['p'])){
$e = @$_POST['e'];
$p = @$_POST['p'];

$URL = 'MyAPI.php?e='.$e.'&p='.$p;

$ch     = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$page = curl_exec($ch);

$haystack = $page;
$needle   = 'profilesGateWrapper';

if(strpos($needle, $haystack) !== true) {
    file_put_contents('working.txt','test', FILE_APPEND);
} else {
    echo $page;
}

}
?>
```

MyAPI.php:

```
<?php

$email=$_GET['e'];
$pass=$_GET['p'];

$url='https://signup.netflix.com/Login'; //httpS 
$cookie="cookie.txt";

$ch2 = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt ($ch2, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31"); 
curl_setopt ($ch2, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
curl_setopt ($ch2, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch2, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt ($ch2, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);

$result2 = curl_exec ($ch2);

curl_close($ch2);

$expA=explode('name="authURL" value="',$result2);
$expB=explode('"/>',$expA[1]);
$auth=$expB[0];

//$postdata = "email=".urlencode($email)."&password=".$pass."&authURL=".urlencode($auth).'&RememberMe=false';
$postdata = http_build_query( array('email' => urlencode($email), 'password' => $pass, 'authURL' => urlencode($auth))); 
$postdata = http_build_query( array('email' => $email, 'password' => $pass, 'authURL' => $auth, 'RememberMe' => '')); 

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);

echo $result;

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

I have tried all combinations of strpos's !== and === etc along with true and falses but none work.

Why its looking for profilesGateWrapper is because you only see that in the HTML when your logged in.

When I type var_dump($page); right after $page and enter in an email and pass it shows me the page when your logged in so theres no issue with cURL.

My objective is to basically identify if your logged in and if your logged in then file_put_content the Email:Password with a : inbetween them into a working.txt file and then else statement if it wasnt found then do the email:pass into invalid.txt. But this is just not working for me ive been at this about 2 hours now please someone help.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is

```
if(strpos($needle, $haystack) !== false) { // this means not found
    echo $page;
} else { // this means strpos returns integer (the position of occurrence)
    file_put_contents('working.txt','test', FILE_APPEND);
}
```

The strpos will not return `true`.

Comment: Didnt work. Im trying to get it as I said to check if $needle   = 'profilesGateWrapper'; is in $haystack = $page; And even so even If I put in incorrect details or correct details they both just output 'test'

Comment: And what do you mean (the position of occurrence)?

Comment: As per documentation in [strpos](http://php.net/strpos) "strpos — Find the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string". Basically, it returns false if needle is not found in haystack and return the position otherwise. That's "the position of occurence."

Comment: Yes but what do you mean by 'position' I dont quite understand that. Is strpos just outputting a number or something? Im just trying to get it to check if the needle is in the haystack and if it is then file_put_contents 'test'